# S3 direct mount screw specifications

Tags: derailleur-front

I need to find replacement s3 direct mount screws.

What are the specifications of these screws?

Comment: I think you're confused, please reconsider. I've done the research and found no info, I also have been building bikes for years, and have no other bolts that work with this mount. It is not really a shopping question, its a standard built into my frame, with no reference (banshee rune)

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Silicabello. You are expected to have done some research, and even though you say you have, I found this on my first try: [eBay](http://m.ebay.com.au/itm/SRAM-Spare-low-direct-mount-S1-S3-screw-kit-453463-/272218107775)

Comment: Andy...did you read the post? Im aware of the whole screw pack from sram...it lists no specifications, I want to know specifically about the mount screws

Comment: ...I wasnt really looking for someone to guess. I'm looking for actual information...not a suggestion to buy things and figure it out, I could have done this on my own. How is a question like this not exactly what stackexchange is for?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and also read through the [help] to see how this site works. You asked *does anyone know where you can get these generically? Or ... Or ...* and even though this post is off topic I answered your first question with "eBay". Please read the links I suggested and edit your question to fit the rules :-)

Comment: Thank you for further derailing this thread...also you linked to SRAM products, I asked for generic, therefore not answering my question at all. How is a mount specific standard in any way off topic? Andy and Moz, if this question disinterests you, could please not post anymore and just let someone else chime in?

Comment: @Silicabello the other users you are referring to are right, however, they should make a simple edit to your question instead of posting a comment longer than an answer about how this isn't a good question. I made an edit to make the question about the screw specs and removed any "buying advice". Good question. Don't be discouraged by other community members.

Comment: "I could have done this on my own" sums it up nicely.

Comment: @ebrohman I'd love to see that answer.

Comment: An S3 is a refrigerator-sized computer.  Do you really want to mount one on your bike?

Comment: @Silicabello Please edit your question to include more detail about what you are looking for. What is an S3? Is it a type of bike? A bike part? What is the research you've done and why didn't it work for you? The more information you provide, the better your answers will be. See our [help pages](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info about [how to write a good question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would like to remind everyone in this comment thread that we require users to [be nice](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) on this site. **Everyone:** please make an effort to be more considerate of your fellow users.

Comment: I think @Silicabello is looking for a screw specification such as M6x25mm socket cap screw to mount an S3 type SRAM direct mount front derailleur.  

There is no need to buy the official kit, there is really not much special about them. You could walk in to a hardware store and come out with a few for < $5 I'm sure, but you have to know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

M5.0x0.8-6H is the bolt size. What do i win?
[image: Per Sram]

I am unsure of the length, but a 10mm costs 58 cents at home depot in the states. I believe S3 mounts use 2 different lengths because of the 5mm offset but i could be wrong.

Comment: There are 6 screws in the pack but this appears to only cover two of them. Any hints on the other four?

Comment: Not that i looked for, or noticed. I just looked for what the actual mount portion used as that was my interpretation of the original question. I'll see if i can find anything though and edit it into the answer if i do.